# Erro no método de intercalar elementos com Mergesort em uma List<Integer>

Tags: java, classificação, lista, merge

Esta parte do algoritmo tem a função de intercalar os elementos de uma `List<Integer>` (lista de números inteiros normal) usando o algoritmo de ordenação Mergesort. **ERRO NA LINHA 7**

```
private static List intercalar(List<Integer> list, int l, int h, int r){
    int i = l, j = h, /*marcador do topo*/t = 0; 
    List<Integer> topo = Arrays.asList(); 

    while(i < h && j < r){ // O(n/2) = 
        if(list.get(i) < list.get(j)){ 
            topo.add(t, list.get(i)); **ERRO AQUI**
            i++; 
        } else { 
            topo.add(t, list.get(j));
            j++; 
        } 
        t++;
    } 

    //anexa o restante das cartas(as cartas q ficaram sozinhas)
    while(i < h){
        topo.add(t, list.get(i));
        t++;
        i++;
    }
    while(j < r){
        topo.add(t, list.get(j));
        t++;
        j++;
    } 

    for(i = l, t = 0 ; i < r ; i++, t++) {
        list.set(i, topo.get(t));
    } 
    return list;
}
```

Apresenta o seguinte erro :

> java.util.UnsupportedOperationException:null (in java.util.AbstractList)

Comment: Amigo presentou o seguinte erro : java.util.List is abstract; cannot be instantiated.

Comment: publiquei uma resposta ali tenta ver se resolve seu problema

Comment: listei os erros que apareceram...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Arrays.asList();
```

Funciona da seguinte forma, caso você tenha um vetor de objetos que queira alocar em uma lista como por exemplo:

```
int[] vet = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
List<int> list1 = Arrays.asList(vet);
```

Neste caso eu aloquei um vetor de tamanho 5 em uma lista, no seu caso você não está alocando nada na lista, logo ele está dando erro porque sua lsita está vazia.
Outra coisa estive observando o seu código e vi que você esta tentando manipular a lista como se fosse um `map` :

```
 topo.add(t, list.get(i)); **ERRO AQUI**
    i++; 
 } else { 
    topo.add(t, list.get(j));
```

Mude para isto:

```
 topo.add(list.get(i)); **ERRO AQUI**
    i++; 
 } else { 
    topo.add(list.get(j));
```

Ou então apenas use:

```
List<int> topo = new ArrayList<int>();
```

Comment: Amigo, usando o List<Integer> topo = new Arrays.asList();  apareceu o seguinte erro: cannot find symbol - class asList e usando List<Integer> topo = new List<Integer>(); apareceu: java.util.List is abstract; cannot be instantiated.

Comment: Editado, tenta pegar meu exemplo

Comment: entendi, então neste meu caso teria q ser uma lista dentro dessa nova lista

Comment: não não teria que ser um vetor dentro da lista, por isso o método se chama Arrays.asList hehe

Comment: nao deu amigo...

Comment: qual foi a alteração que voce fez ?

Comment: coloquei os elementos da minha primeira lista dentro de um vetor e depois criei a nova lista passando o vetor do jeito que vc ensinou. Deu o erro de null na linha do add() de novo...

Comment: pode editar sua pergunta e colocar e mostrar o que foi editado ?

Comment: //Integer[] vet = new Integer[list.size()];
        Integer[] vet = {5,7,7,8,8,1,1,5,5,7,7,8,8,1,1,5,5,7,7,8,8,1};
        //for(int z = 0; z < list.size(); z++){    
        //    vet[z] = list.get(z);
        //}
        List<Integer> topo = Arrays.asList(vet);

Comment: editei minha resposta, de uma analisada e verifique

Comment: deu exatamente o mesmo erro...

Comment: voce tem que verificar tmb se o valor j e h não estão estourando a lista, tipo caso a lista tenha o tamanho 10 e j ou h for 11 entendeu ? seu código está meio confuso então te recomendo começar debugar ele desde a primeira linha tambem recomendo que use List<int> topo = new ArrayList<int>();

Comment: consegui amigo, muito obrigado !

Comment: qual foi a alteração ?

Comment: `List<Integer> topo = new ArrayList();
        
        while(i < h && j < r){
            if(list.get(i) < list.get(j)){ 
                topo.add(t, list.get(i)); 
                i++; 
            } else { 
                topo.add(t, list.get(j));
                j++; 
            } 
            t++; 
        }`